# Как из разных функций отправлять по одному API информацию о выполнении этой функции?

Tags: python

Доброго времени суток!

***Суть***: Есть софтина на Python, со своим API и суть ее работы, давайте представим, заключается в автоматической готовке пиццы.
У нее есть набор модулей, например, модуль для работы с печью, модуль для работы с автоматом для разрезания теста и т.д. Каждый модуль - набор функций. В ходе выполнения каждой функции, с помощью команды ***print***  в стандартный поток вывода выводится текущий статус.
(Ну например **print('Запускается печь...')**.

***Задача***: Мне нужно, что бы эти статусы отображались в стандартном потоке вывода и отправлялись по API (в данном случае, API - это экземпляр класса, с помощью методов которого осуществляются различные операции, нас интересует метод broadcast_sending, который отправляет заданные аргументы всем клиентам, которые к этому API подключены (подключение по сокетам)).
Т.е. я в другом модуле сделал функцию:

```
def send_status(*data):
    print(data)
    global api
    api.broadcast_sending(data)
```

Теперь, во всех функциях в других модулях я заменил просто ***print*** на ***send_status***, таким образом, информация попадает и на стандартный поток вывода, и клиенту, который был подключен по к этому API и дал, собственно, команду на начало заготовки пиццы..
Но мне кажется, что я делаю что-то неправильно, нет ли решения изящней? Спасибо.

Answer (score 0):

Вы можете использовать модуль `logging`. Он позволяет подключить различные `handler'ы`. Делаете свой вариант `handler`, который, к примеру будет отправлять `post` запросы с логами по адресу и добавляете его через `.addHandler(api)`.

В качестве примеры приведу вариант, когда по разному выводится сообщение в лог.

```
import logging

class APIRequestHandler(logging.Handler):       
    def emit(self, record):
        try:
            msg = self.format(record)
            print('api:: ' + msg)
        except Exception:
            self.handleError(record)

class ModStringHandler(logging.Handler):       
    def emit(self, record):
        try:
            msg = self.format(record)
            print('print:: ' + msg)
        except Exception:
            self.handleError(record)

formatter = logging.Formatter('%(asctime)s - %(name)s - %(levelname)s - %(message)s')

api = APIRequestHandler()   
#api.setLevel(logging.INFO) 
api.setFormatter(formatter)
mod = ModStringHandler()
#mod.setLevel(logging.INFO) 
mod.setFormatter(formatter)

logger = logging.Logger('test')
logger.setLevel(logging.INFO)
logger.addHandler(api)
logger.addHandler(mod)
logger.info('test - info')
logger.warning('test - warning')
```

Вывод:

```
api:: 2021-07-21 22:34:02,131 - test - INFO - test - info
mod:: 2021-07-21 22:34:02,131 - test - INFO - test - info
api:: 2021-07-21 22:34:02,132 - test - WARNING - test - warning
mod:: 2021-07-21 22:34:02,132 - test - WARNING - test - warning
```